# "Update Model from Database" wizard is deleting mappings of renamed POCO classes

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-database-first

I'm building an application using EF 5 to talk to an existing Oracle database. I'm not allowed to change any part of the DB schema. I have generated my model from the database using the VS2012 wizard, and all classes are named after their Oracle counterparts.

The naming of objects in the database is QUITE_UGLY_AND_INCONSISTENT, so I'd like to rename the POCO classes and properties. I can easily do that from the EDM Designer. As a result, I get neatly named class and property names, that are mapped to the UGLY_NAMED tables from the DB. I can successfully perform queries and everything works smoothly. Exactly what I wanted.

However, when I need to add new tables to the model, I run the "Update Model from Database" wizard and check the additional tables to import. It suddenly lists my renamed (but still correctly mapped) classes under the Delete tab, saying it can't find them in the database. When I click Finish, my existing classes are unmapped and I have to manually re-map each property to its corresponding DB column... Or roll back to the previous version of the EDMX file from version control.

I'm looking for what *you* think would be the most elegant solution to this problem, since I need the application to be as maintainable as possible. I strongly favour an approach that lets me auto-generate new classes from the database while preserving the existing renamed objects and their mappings.

- Am I overlooking some way to prevent the Update Model wizard from deleting my existing mappings?
- Should I use a different approach to renaming the generated classes?
- Should I leave the generated classes unchanged and instead construct sanely-named wrapper classes that are exposed to the rest of my application?
- Should I refrain from auto-generation and instead go for a code-first approach? This is a very unfavorable option, because I need the time spent on manual model coding and mapping to be as little as possible. Adding objects will be a very frequent task.
- Should I perhaps even use a different ORM altogether..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the culprit myself: running the "Generate Database from Model" wizard due to a recommendation in an article I read somewhere. It changed all the model's underlying table and column names to SQL Server standard names ([dbo].[Customers].[CustomerID] etc.).